# How to fetch the values from object of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my object is like below

```
Facility = [{
       HospitalName : "one",
       HospitalAddress : "Address"
       Beds : [{ICU : 6, 
                Outpatient : 7}]

 }, {
       HospitalName : "Two",
       HospitalAddress : "Address"
       Beds : [{ICU : 2, 
                Outpatient : 15}]

 } ]
```

I am using foreach to loop and calculates

```
 Facility.forEach(function (element) {

   var Beds_Details = element.Beds;
  console.log(Beds_Details);   // Here I am getting Icu and all in [0]
   Sum_ICU  += Beds_Details[0].ICU ;   //Here getting undefined
   Sum_Outpatient  += Beds_Details[0].Outpatient ;
});
```

In the above **Beds_Details[0].ICU** I am expecting the number but I am getting undefined. How to get the number.

Comment: have you initialized `Sum_ICU` with number `0`?

Comment: eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

initialize the variable outside the foreach. And also your json missing a `,` after `HospitalAddress : "Address"` field

```js
var Facility = [{
       HospitalName : "one",
       HospitalAddress : "Address",
       Beds : [{ICU : 6, 
                Outpatient : 7}]

 }, {
       HospitalName : "Two",
       HospitalAddress : "Address",
       Beds : [{ICU : 2, 
                Outpatient : 15}]

 } ]
 var Sum_Outpatient = '';
 var Sum_ICU = 0;
 Facility.forEach(function (element) {debugger 
   var Beds_Details = element.Beds;

   Sum_ICU  += parseInt(Beds_Details[0].ICU) ;  
   Sum_Outpatient  += Beds_Details[0].Outpatient ;
   
});


   console.log(Sum_ICU)
```

Comment: My bad, Now its getting work I have initialize outside of function and not inherited here.

Comment: @charan tej ok. and if you want to get the sum of that field make sure to use the `parseInt`. otherwise, it will append the numbers

Comment: Without append it is correctly working because I am intialize it as a number with 0

Answer (score 0):

Could have to do with the fact that you are missing a `,` after the `HospitalAddress` member.

```js
var facility = [{
       HospitalName : "one",
       HospitalAddress : "Address",
       Beds : [{ICU : 6, 
               Outpatient : 7}]

 }, {
       HospitalName : "Two",
       HospitalAddress : "Address",
       Beds : [{ICU : 2, 
                Outpatient : 15}]

 }];


facility.forEach(function (element) {

   var Beds_Details = element.Beds;
   console.log(Beds_Details);          // Here I am getting Icu and all in [0]
   console.log(Beds_Details[0].ICU);   // Here getting undefined
   console.log(Beds_Details[0].Outpatient);
});
```

Comment: My bad, Now its getting work I have initialize outside of function and not inherited here.

Answer (score 0):

1- There's a missing comma in your JSON after `HospitalAddress`

2- You should initialize your `Sum_ICU` and `Sum_Outpatient` outside the loop before assigning values.

Comment: My bad, Now its getting work I have initialize  outside of function and not inherited here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of Array in Bed object and because of that it is showing [0].

The updated code is as follows :

```
Facility = [{
       HospitalName : "one",
       HospitalAddress : "Address",
       Beds : {ICU : 6, 
                Outpatient : 7}

 }, {
       HospitalName : "Two",
       HospitalAddress : "Address",
       Beds : {ICU : 2, 
                Outpatient : 15}

 } ]
```

And For loop will be as follows:

```
Sum_ICU=0;
Sum_Outpatient=0;
Facility.forEach(function (element) {
   var Beds_Details = element.Beds;
  console.log(Beds_Details);   // Here I am getting Icu and all in [0]
   Sum_ICU  += Beds_Details.ICU ;   //Here getting undefined
   Sum_Outpatient  += Beds_Details.Outpatient ;
});
```